# Distributing a float value between 2 floats

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, unity-game-engine

Im sorry, but i couldnt find any helpful resource for this.
In Unity, there are two Wheel Colliders A and B, with their own Speed values, which are attached to a car. This car also has another script with a CarSpeed value.So what i want to do is, distribute this CarSpeed value between the Speed Values of Wheel Colliders A and B, and i want to that that based on another value which is called the AllWheelDriveLevel, which determines whether the Speed is evenly distributed between all the wheels or not. So, helping me figure out an algorithmic method for this would be helpful, thank you ! :D

Comment: could you give us an example of input and desired output? do you mean a simple ratio computation, or do we need to take acceleration into account? how many variables are involved?

Comment: There is one float, CarSpeed, which i want to distribute between two other float variables,named FrontWheelSpeed and BackWheelSpeed, based on a value called AllWheelDrive, which determines whether the car runs on all wheels, front wheels or back wheels

Comment: sorry, I still don't get it. so allwheeldrive is a boolean to switch between 2WD and 4WD? especially unclear is what "distribute" should mean. when you have a speed of 100 rpm it does not mean that the front and rear axle make 50 rpm each!? are you modeling after a real powertrain, that would allow varying speed on all four wheels by means of slip and differentials?

Comment: AllWheelDrive is an int, which goes upto 5. At value 1, for example, the whole CarSpeed is distributed between the car wheels (which are 2 in number, as its a 2D game) in the ratio 5:1, that is, if CarSpeed is 600, then BackWheelSpeed will be 500 and FrontWheelSpeed will be 100. When AllWheelDrive's value is 5, the CarSpeed will be evenly distributed ie FrontWheelSpeed = 300 and BackWheelSpeed = 300

Comment: in this case I think this is plain elementary school maths. when you have just five discrete ratios, hardcode them in a switch statement. example: `case 1: frontwheelspeed = carspeed / 6 * 5; rearwheelspeed = carspeed / 6 * 1;` etc. but what that means physically, is just odd. a stress test setup for tires, engine and transmission :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U should be able to figure out solution with this example;

```
{
public int allwheeldrive = 1;
private List<GameObject> wheels = new List<GameObject>();
private float totalwheelpower;
private List<bool> activewheels = new List<bool>();
private void Awake()
{
    int four = 2;
    while (four != 0)
    {
        GameObject wheel = new GameObject();
        bool wheelactive = false;
        activewheels.Add(wheelactive);
        wheels.Add(wheel);
        four--;
    }
}

void distributepower()
{
    float powerwheel1;
    float powerwheel2;

    switch (allwheeldrive)
    {
        case 1:
            powerwheel1 = (totalwheelpower / 3) * 2;
            powerwheel2 = (totalwheelpower / 3) * 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            //fill out what other possibilities u want
            break;

    }

}
}
```

Comment: This is close to what i want, but i want to distribute the speed according to a ratio i set eg FrontWheelSpeed : BackWheelSpeed = 2:3 according to the AllWheelDrive int variable

Comment: Hardcode the value of your ratios in floats ; and use a switch statement for each ratio. depending on what your AllWheelDrive int variable  is.

Comment: I updated the example this should cover what u want, i started learning code for scratch 40 days ago, try to write code yourself and post your code if u get stuck people will help u.This way u learn fast.

Comment: Can you explains the lines                                                                                    powerwheel1 = (totalwheelpower / 3) * 2;
powerwheel2 = (totalwheelpower / 3) * 1; Why did you divide it by 3? And multiply by 2 and 1 respectively?

Comment: It divides thetotalpower between two floats; Divided by 3 and multiplied by the ratio u want for that wheel. This is very basic math. Please try some stuff on your own.